If I buy a piece of property with a trailer pad, and that pad is occupied, and the trailer occupying the pad is excluded from the sale, can I junk it?
The small [12-14 foot] travel trailer has a hitch lock, wheels and flat tires, it may be licensed (something that only requires paying a fee to the state) but the tail lights have been removed and it displays no tags. The seller is willing to state on the contract that he is not receiving any compensation for the trailer being there. He says the trailer was owned by a prior tenant who left over a year ago.

It seems that including the trailer in the sale would give you more of a right to dispose of it than not.  Because excluding it presumes the earlier tenant still has a claim on it and burdens you with resolving the ownership question.  Since the seller had a contract with the previous tenant it would seem better for them to disposition the trailer.  There are laws that deal with abandoned property, what state are you in?

Thanks, it's a point of contention in negotiating the sale. The trailer's presence  completely diminishes the value of the property. In my ideal world I want nothing to do with the trailer, but in the seller's ideal world I take both the property and the trailer. If I do that I need to be compensated, and that probably should include my time and an hour of an attorney's time to review the contract, especially this and one other issue that I posted separately. I was wondering if the seller was just lazy, or if he knew something that I did not.

It seems the diminished value might provide the compensation...  It's simply a matter for you and the seller to determine who does the work, but your ability to disposition is hampered by not being a party to the agreement with the previous tenant.  My first comment was based on a perceived flaw in your logic.  i.e., if the trailer was included in the sale it would be yours to dispose of, whereas excluding it leaves ownership in question.

Thanks, I have spoken to the village police. If I show them the executed contract to show that I own the property, they will tow the trailer to their impound lot, so that's resolved.

No.
The trailer is excluded from the sale. This means the trailer is supposedly the property of someone else.
The property was left behind by a former tenant who left more than 12 months ago. It would depend on what that tenant's lease said about any property left behind: was it to be stored for a specific time for retrieval or considered abandoned then? In either case, the trailer might have become the property of the former landlord, or still be the left tenant's property.
As a trailer is a road vehicle, it also is required to have a VIN. This could be used to try and locate the last registered owner's details, and if known, current address. Often, the DMV might even assist in providing information on where the VIN is located (or do a VIN inspection on the vehicle) and then inform how to proceed, such as if the vehicle could be considered "abandoned property" aka a "Barn find" based on the duration the registration is expired.

I called the village police non-emergency number and right or wrong if I show them the executed contract for the property they will tow the travel trailer to their impound lot.

@CallmeA See? that's also a solution. It will end up for auction if not retrieved from there, and then somebody will have good title.

Then its a win-win-win (me, seller, eventual buyer of trailer).
